# Can't access Public variable Outside Jar in Java Swing

Tags: java, jar, static-variables

I have a public static variable in class A this class is defined in Jar A.
   I am try to call this variable in Class B in Jar B.The source code of Jar A is attached as a relative path to jar B.Before every thing was working fine and i can access public variables of Class A of Jar A in Class B of Jar B . But now the new defined variable is not seen in Class B of Jar B. I have clean and rebuild the jar A several times and paste in lib of jar A but nothing works for me. Lots of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution to my problem that i was pasting the jar A to the lib of dist folder of Jar B, while pasting to the main library of Jar B fixed my problem.